# Using profiles with multi target deploys

Tags: google-cloud-deploy

Google Cloud Deploy supports multi targets by creating a child target. However the profiles configuration is a part of the pipeline config so during rendering the profiles go missing.

e.g. let us assume I have a web-server and a jobs-server that I want to deploy in parallel. The following config sort of works

```
apiVersion: deploy.cloud.google.com/v1
kind: DeliveryPipeline
metadata:
  name: parallel-deploy-example
description: Parallel deploy Example
serialPipeline:
  stages:
    - targetId: all-servers
      profiles: [profile1, profile2]
---
apiVersion: deploy.cloud.google.com/v1
kind: Target
metadata:
  name: all-servers
description: Deploy all servers
multiTarget:
  targetIds:
    - web-server
    - jobs-server
---
apiVersion: deploy.cloud.google.com/v1
kind: Target
metadata:
  name: web-server
  labels:
    service-type: web server
description: staging web us-central1
run:
  location: projects/something/locations/us-central1
---
apiVersion: deploy.cloud.google.com/v1
kind: Target
metadata:
  name: jobs-server
  labels:
    service-type: jobs
description: jobs server
run:
  location: projects/something/locations/us-central1
```

Now While I can pass profile1 profile2 to both servers I can't pass a profile specifically for web-server and a different profile for jobs server.

However when doing it serially since each step has a profiles array I can give them their own profile.

Is there some secret config I am missing or is this a limitation I have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct in that you cannot pass separate profiles to Cloud Deploy and have those independently applied on a per child target basis. The multi-target capability is intended to deploy the same application/job across multiple targets but not to concurrently coordinate deploy of independent services/jobs. If you need to configure the same service/job deployment across multiple child targets you can however adjust these definitions on a per child target basis using [deploy parameters](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/parameters).

The above said, treating your service/job rollouts as two separate targets in a serial progression will support their independent delivery. One workaround to having these deployed concurrently would be to use an Automation.

In this approach, consider the following:

Serial progression:
[target A (service - dev)] --> [target B (job - dev) --> [target C (service -staging)] --> [target D (job - staging)]

When creating a Release - you would have to coordinate an initial rollout for the release to both A and B targets at the same time. You can do so by creating a release using [--disable-initial-rollout](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deploy/releases/create#--disable-initial-rollout) and then using the promote [--to-target](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deploy/releases/promote#--to-target) flag to deploy the service/job to A and B concurrently (two separate, but concurrent, release create calls).

However, as B is successfully deployed, you could use an [Automation resource](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/automation-resource#the_automation_resource) with two separate [promoteRelease rules](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/automation-rules#promoterelease_rule) to automatically promote from B to (C AND D) at the same time. In this way, upon successful deployment to B automation will initiate forward successful deployments to the next successful 2 (or 'n') targets.

I hope this is of some aid!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I came across deploy parameters and was looking into it as well. 

I think that overall these approaches seem a bit like workarounds. One of the things that I found that was really neat was the fact that if I added an approval step for our staging pipeline i could view the manifest diff. But if i go with the serial approach, I would need to look at different reviews instead of approving one review which would approve the whole deploy. 

Right now our approach is to use automation to auto promote from service -> job but parallel would be the ideal solution